# How to zoom to a place by street name in Google Maps API in Flash?

Tags: flash, google-maps, geocoding

I'm sorry if I'm asking a basic question, but I can't find it anywhere and I don't understand too much from the provided documentation. Basically, I want to make a *.SWF in which the user inserts an address in the first frame, then in the second frame Google Maps shows that place. The problem is that I don't know how to zoom on a point without LatLng parameter. Probably, Geocoding would be the solution, but as I said earlier, I don't understand how it works in Flash. Could someone please either post a few lines or direct me to an example of geocoding in Flash? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a com.google.maps.services.ClientGeocoder for that.

Here are some code fragments, not complete code, but it may give you something to start with:

```
import com.google.maps.services.ClientGeocoder;
import com.google.maps.services.GeocodingEvent;

var geocoder:ClientGeocoder = new ClientGeocoder();

geocoder.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_SUCCESS, onGeocodeDone);
geocoder.addEventListener(GeocodingEvent.GEOCODING_FAILURE, onGeocodeFault);

geocoder.geocode("The address goes here");

function onGeocodeDone(e:GeocodingEvent):void
{
   trace("lat: " + e.response.placemarks[0].point.lat());
   trace("lng: " + e.response.placemarks[0].point.lng());
}

function onGeocodeFault(e:GeocodingEvent):void
{
   trace("Geocoding failed: " + e.status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to give it a try. Really appreciate it :).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lars's answer, the way to set the map to the result of the geocode (including zooming to an appropriate level based on the accuracy of the result), is like this:

```
_map.setCenter(placemarks[0].point);

var box:Object = placemarks[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox;
var bounds:LatLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(
    new LatLng(box.south, box.west), 
    new LatLng(box.north, box.east));
var zoom:int = _map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds);
_map.setZoom(zoom);
```

The reference for these fields is taken from this post:

https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-for-flash/browse_thread/thread/1a6ede093d053903

Which references this sample:

http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/GeocodingDetails/GeocodingDetails.html